# C# Color hues for different values

Tags: c#, colors, range, rgb, color-scheme

I would like some advice on how to accomplish the following within C#. I would like to plot a "color", the exact color will be determined by a property value, for the sake of this example let's assume it's a percentage.

Ideally I'd like the user to specify five colors.

```
  Negative MAX
  Negative MIN
  Even
  Positive MIN
  Positive MAX
```

The user is only specifying colors for each level, not the value which determines Min and Max.

Using this data, I would like to be able to calculate a color based on a percentage. i.e. 57% would result in a color hue in between Positive MIN and Positive MAX. Any help or advice for this is appreciated.

Comment: please clear your question up, I don't really understand what you're asking!

Comment: hopefully that explains what I am after. If there is something unclear still please let me know.

Comment: This looks answered, do you need anything else?

Answer (score 0):

To interpolate between two colors you just interpolate each color channel

```
Color color1 = Color.Red;
Color color2 = Color.Green;
double fraction = 0.3;
Color color3 = Color.FromArgb(
    (int)(color1.R * fraction + color2.R * (1 - fraction)),
    (int)(color1.G * fraction + color2.G * (1 - fraction)),
    (int)(color1.B * fraction + color2.B * (1 - fraction)));
```

To interpolate along your scale you need to decide what exact percentage values your "steps" have and project your target value that a fraction between two of those color steps.

Answer (score 0):

Using the function copied [from here](http://viziblr.com/news/2011/12/1/drawing-a-color-hue-wheel-with-c.html), you can convert the hues back into RGB colors. This function assumes has all inputs and outputs in on a 0..1 scale, so you'll need to divide by color.GetHue() by 255. Below the function is some sample code using a set of percentages; implement DisplayColor in the UI of your choice to see the results.

```
public static void HSVToRGB(double H, double S, double V, out double R, out double G, out double B)
{
    if (H == 1.0)
    {
        H = 0.0;
    }

    double step = 1.0/6.0;
    double vh = H/step;

    int i = (int) System.Math.Floor(vh);

    double f = vh - i;
    double p = V*(1.0 - S);
    double q = V*(1.0 - (S*f));
    double t = V*(1.0 - (S*(1.0 - f)));

    switch (i)
    {
        case 0:
            {
                R = V;
                G = t;
                B = p;
                break;
            }
        case 1:
            {
                R = q;
                G = V;
                B = p;
                break;
            }
        case 2:
            {
                R = p;
                G = V;
                B = t;
                break;
            }
        case 3:
            {
                R = p;
                G = q;
                B = V;
                break;
            }
        case 4:
            {
                R = t;
                G = p;
                B = V;
                break;
            }
        case 5:
            {
                R = V;
                G = p;
                B = q;
                break;
            }
        default: 
            {
                // not possible - if we get here it is an internal error
                throw new ArgumentException();
            }
    }
}

Color min = Color.Blue;
Color max = Color.Green;

float minHue = min.GetHue() / 255;
float maxHue = max.GetHue() / 255;

float scale = maxHue - minHue;

float[] percents = new float[] { .05F, .15F, .40F, .70F, .85F, .95F };

foreach (var pct in percents) {
    float curHue = minHue + (scale * pct);
    double r, g, b;
    HSVToRGB(curHue, 1.0, 1.0, out r, out g, out b);

    Color curColor = Color.FromArgb((int)(r * 255), (int)(g * 255), (int)(b * 255));
    DisplayColor(curColor);
}
```

Comment: It should be noted some min/max colors will result in scales larger than 1, which makes me think something isn't quite right, but this is very close to what you're looking for.